# Bluetooth Scanning

Tags: bluetooth, windows-iot, c#

I'm looking to build an app that scans bluetooth and collects the visible info from devices without pairing. I'm using C# and so far I've got my app listing out all of the pi's devices using DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync()

How do I pick the bluetooth from this list, and how do I get the bluetooth antenna to actually scan for bluetooth devices? I've read about 32feet.NET, but it doesnt want to seem to work with a UWP app, also I don't want the entire tech based on a library that could be discontinued. I'd rather it be done with built-ins in the .NET framework if possible.

Comment: You should be able to do this with the .NET API's - Honestly, you should try and search StackOverflow for C# related topics about this. 32feet is nice but I have managed to do it without that for Xamarin specific applications. I do not think this question fits this exchange very well as its just a C# .NET question.